# Get date of last update for a view

Tags: 7, views

Is there an easy way to check when I last made changes to a particular view or views display?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there isn't.  If you look at the views_view and views_display tables in the Drupal database, that information simply isn't stored.

I even checked whether you can get to info like that if you're using the Features module with views, but even that only lets you know if a view has been updated since your last created feature, but gives no information about the date of any changes...